EntraID Graph Query - Filter Applications with at least one owner
I am trying to filter out EntraID applications which has at least one owner assigned.
As per the Microsoft documentation, Owners supports filter based on count.
Directory objects that are owners of the application. Read-only. Nullable. Supports $expand, $filter (/$count eq 0, /$count ne 0, /$count eq 1, /$count ne 1), and $select nested in $expand.
Here is the query I am trying. Appreciate any help on this.
Cheers !

Filtering will work, but you need to add the request header ConsistencyLevel with the value eventual and the query must contain $count=true parameter.
Applications with at least one owner
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications?$filter=owners/$count ne 0&$count=true&$select=id,displayName
ConsistencyLevel:eventual

When filtering applications by the number of owners, you can't expand owners (expand and filter on owners is not supported in one query)
If you are using PowerShell, you need to escape $ character
Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Headers $TargetEnvironments.Header -Uri "graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications?`$filter=owners/`$count ne 0&`$count=true&`$select=id,displayName"


Thanks for the guidance. However, I see that the consistencyLevel was already set to eventual in my case, but still the response I am getting has applications which dont have any ownership defined.     I am using the below code. And header has consistency level set to eventual.                                                                                                                   Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Headers $TargetEnvironments.Header -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications?$filter=owners/$count ne 0&$count=true&$select=id,displayName"

@Shabarinath If you are using PowerShell, you need to escape $ check updated answer

Thanks for that. Now, it works as expected !
Cheers.

It's much better than my code.

It seems that this cannot be achieved with one request, two requests are required

list applications
list owners

## step 1: get graph token

$tenantId           = ""
$clientId           = ""
$clientSecret       = ""

$headers = @{
    "Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}

$uri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/oauth2/v2.0/token" -f $tenantId

$body = @{
    grant_type    = "client_credentials"
    scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
    client_id     = $clientId
    client_secret = $clientSecret
}

$token = $(Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $uri -Body $body -Headers $headers).access_token

## step 2:  list all applications

$headers2 = @{
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
    "Authorization" = "Bearer " + $token
}

$allAppIdUri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications"

$allAppId = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $allAppIdUri -Headers $headers2

## step 3: foreach all the applications and find out the owner details

$owners = @()

foreach($item in $allAppId.value){

    $ownerUri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/{0}/owners" -f $item.id
    $res = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $ownerUri -Headers $headers2
    
    if($($null -ne $res.value) -and $($res.value.Count -gt 1)){
        $tmp = @{
            id          = $item.id
            name        = $item.displayName
            owners      = $res.value
            onwersCount = $res.value.Count
        }
        $owners += $tmp
    }
}
$owners | Format-Table


